# Как инициализировать зубчатый массив из List?

Tags: c#, .net, telegram-bot

Сабж.
Вот не знаю правильно ли я вопрос задал, возможно он звучит по другому, если не правильно то исправьте пожалуйста.
Есть такой код для вывода кнопок в телеграмм боте:

```C#
// using Telegram.Bot.Types.ReplyMarkups;

InlineKeyboardMarkup inlineKeyboard = new(new []
    {
        // first row
        new []
        {
            InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData(text: "1.1", callbackData: "11"),
        },
        // second row
        new []
        {
            InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData(text: "2.1", callbackData: "21"),
        },
    });

Message sentMessage = await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
    chatId: chatId,
    text: "A message with an inline keyboard markup",
    replyMarkup: inlineKeyboard,
    cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Мне нужно отправить в конструктор количество массивов равное List.Count().
Я создаю зубчатый массив

```
 InlineKeyboardButton[][] test = new InlineKeyboardButton[tokens.Count()][];
```

Но дальше не понимаю как его заполнить.
Пытаюсь так но получаю ошибку

```C#
for (int i = 0; i < test.Count(); i++)
{
 test[i][0] = InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData(text: tokens[i].Name, callbackData: tokens[i].Name);
}



System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

Answer (score 0):

> Как инициализировать зубчатый массив из List?

```
var someList = new List<List<int>>();
```

это инициализирует лист листов.

> Мне нужно отправить в конструктор количество массивов равное List.Count(). Я создаю зубчатый массив

```
var b = someList.Select( a => a.toArray() ).toArray();
```

превратит из `List<List<int>>` в массив массивов интов

Comment: Нет, это не подходит.

Comment: что конкретно не так? дай мне точный формат входных данных и точный формат данных которые должны получится на выходе

Comment: Мне нужно заполнить массив с своими данными InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData(text: tokens[i].Name, callbackData: tokens[i].Name); либо в конструкторе класса передать массивов со своими данными в количестве list.count()

Comment: это не формат данных это какая-то функция, возможно фабрика.... А формат данных какой? И какой входной формат данных?

Comment: Конструктор принимает IEnumerable<IEnumerable<InlineKeyboardButton>> inlineKeyboard

Comment: ну тогда конструктор принимает как List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> так и массив массивов InlineKeyboardButton. То есть ничего городить не нужно.

Comment: InlineKeyboardButton это  new []
        {
            InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData(text: "1.1", callbackData: "11"),
        }, И вот это мне нужно заполнить своими данными

Comment: нет, `InlineKeyboardButton` это `InlineKeyboardButton`, а не `InlineKeyboardButton[]`. Ты в своем примере показал как ты инициализируешь `InlineKeyboardButton[]`. То есть ты делаешь лишнее действие - инициализируешь массив. А создание только одной кнопки это `InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData(text: "1.1", callbackData: "11")`